# Install windows from FLASH USB. Software

Tags: windows-xp, usb, operating-systems

Please direct me to software which can create bootable USB with winxp on it.

Yesterday I tried to create such on WIN7 and failed, I guess because of win7 admin rights.
Moreover I created such usb on winxp, but some hal.dll file was missing, so I failed to do it. Is there any good software which can create WinXP SP3 bootable USB without any bugs?

Comment: HAL.dll was probably not missing, HAL stands for Hardware Abstraction Layer - which is a set of routines embedded into Windows to allow programs to access the underlying hardware. If the hardware changes then it usually reports errors. [More info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_abstraction)

Comment: BUt how this information should help me? Meaning what should I do to repair current state?

Comment: I was pointing out that just replacing the hal.dll wouldn't fix your problem. Without using something like 'WinToFlash' (see Moif's answer below) it's doubtful that just copying the installation files to another source is enough. Differences in filesystems etc.

Comment: Oh I see, ty. I used software called PETOUSB and BootSect and some other tool which copied files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use WinToFlash. It enables you to copy Windows installation sources to bootable USB:

http://wintoflash.com/community/en/

> WinToFlash is likely to make a big difference to the way you work. It will make life a lot easier for you. Quickly and simply install the program you needs and in no time at all you will find yourself writing essays on Windows and using your USB. The WinToFlash makes the job hassle free for you.
>
> WinToFlash is software for transfer your Windows XP, Windows 2003, Windows Vista, Windows 2008, Windows 7, Windows 8 Setup from CD or DVD to USB in some mouse clicks. This is about you can install your Windows from flash drive or card, HDD, etc. to your computer or netbook.
>
> And this is not all it can do. WinToFlash can transfer your live CD or DVD to USB card, for example, BartPE. After all you can erase your USB media and format it with Windows for everyday use.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: What about Windows license?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [linux liveusb creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/).Dont panic by its name It can make Live USB for windows also.